# background not show in repeat-y

Tags: css, background, repeat

background of left and right div(column) not show.but when add "height: xx px" are shown.
but my content div is flexible.how solve this problem?
tnx. 
my code is :

```
<div style="background:url("image/l.png") repeat-y;float:left;width:3px;height:auto;" id="left"></div>
<div style="width: 613px;background:#fff;" id="center">
  <p>contents</p>
  <p>contents</p>
  <p>contents</p>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
</div>
<div style="background:url("image/r.png") repeat-y;float:left;width:3px;height:auto;" id="right"></div>
```

Comment: Please separate your CSS from your HTML. It's not 1997 any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine `l` and `r`.png and make them 1 background image repeating vertically on #center, or if necessary put them on the parent of the center element.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the double quotes... for best practice, try to keep your css external. What hunter did is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the double quotes. You don't need quotes when you use url().